# How to make a phone call using intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call, android-implicit-intent, android-phone-call

I'm using the following code to make a call in Android but it is giving me security exception please help.

```
 posted_by = "111-333-222-4";

 String uri = "tel:" + posted_by.trim() ;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Exception

```
11-25 14:47:01.661: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:111-333-222-4 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{43d32508 302:com.Finditnear/10026} (pid=302, uid=10026) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1214)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at com.Finditnear.PostDetail$2$1$1$1.onClick(PostDetail.java:604)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:884)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Every thing is fine.

i just placed call permissions tag before application tag in manifest file

and now every thing is working fine.

Comment: See my answer below on how to achieve almost the same without the need for a permission and with a chance for the user to not actually make the call.

Comment: Also, be aware of telephony-less devices : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300036/693752

Comment: further info as suggested by Snicolas http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/solution-to-make-an-android-app-visible-to-all-devices-in-google-play-when-using-specific-feature-2/

Comment: You will not be able to submit your app to the play store this way. Use Action Dial instead as your Intent and remove Call Phone from the manifest.

Answer (score 420):

You can use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. This shows the dialer with the number already entered, but allows the user to decide whether to actually make the call or not. `ACTION_DIAL` does not require the `CALL_PHONE` permission.

Comment: ACTION_DIAL not require permission, this is an important difference compared with ACTION_CALL intent :)

Answer (score 268):

This demo will helpful for you...

On call button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Permission in Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**EDIT IN 2021**

You should write it in your manifest file but at the same time you should ask in runtime.Like this code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                REQUEST_CODE)

        } else {

// else block means user has already accepted.And make your phone call here.

}
```

And if you want you can override onRequestPermissionsResult to give user better experience if you write same code with else block here your user will not need to click on your button again after you give permission it will directly call.

Comment: +1 for "tel:" . I had call instead and got no intent exception. Tnx

Comment: This simply does not work in my nexus 4. It opens the dialer showing the phone number but does not start the call without user interaction. Any sugestion?

Comment: What's the difference between the code in the question and in this answer? How does it solve the problem?

Comment: This opens skype for me.

Comment: Please add Call Phone Run time Permission too

Answer (score 230):

More elegant option:

```
String phone = "+34666777888";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This works without adding anything to Manifest like the previous answer

Comment: No runtime permissions required. +1

Comment: if you are running this code outside the Activity class then you need to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your intent.

Answer (score 109):

Use the action ACTION_DIAL in your intent, this way you won't need any permission. The reason you need the permission with ACTION_CALL is to make a phone call without any action from the user.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0987654321"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is better in case where you don't need to ask permission.

Comment: There's a missing semicolon in the second line of the code. perfect answer!

Answer (score 38):

### IMPORTANT NOTE:

If you use `Intent.ACTION_CALL` you must add `CALL_PHONE` permission.

Its okey only if you don't want your app to show up in google play for tablets that doesn't take SIM card or doesn't have GSM.

#### IN YOUR ACTIVITY:

```
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Constants.CALL_CENTER_NUMBER));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

#### MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

So if it is not critical feature to your app, try to stay away from adding `CALL_PHONE` permission.

#### OTHER SOLUTION:

Is to show the Phone app with the number written in on the screen, so user will only need to click call button:

```
            Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Constants.CALL_CENTER_NUMBER));
            startActivity(dialIntent);
```

**No permission needed for this.**

Answer (score 25):

Just the simple oneliner without any additional permissions needed:

```
private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));
}
```

Answer (score 19):

use this full code

```
          Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
          callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(PhoneNum.trim())));
          callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: This technique worked for me, although I had to change Intent.ACTION_DIAL to Intent.Anction_CALL.

Answer (score 13):

**Request Permission in manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**For calling use this code**

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:99xxxxxxxx"));
try {
    startActivity(in);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Could not find an activity to place the call.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need the permission since your app is not calling itself, but asking the dedicated app (which has the permission) to do it.

Answer (score 12):

```
// Java
String mobileNumber = "99XXXXXXXX";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); // Action for what intent called for
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: " + mobileNumber)); // Data with intent respective action on intent
startActivity(intent);

// Kotlin
val mobileNumber = "99XXXXXXXX"
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_DIAL // Action for what intent called for
intent.data = Uri.parse("tel: $mobileNumber") // Data with intent respective action on intent
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 11):

Permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Complete code:

```
private void onCallBtnClick(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        phoneCall();
    }else {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            phoneCall();
        }else {
            final String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
            //Asking request Permissions
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, 9);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    boolean permissionGranted = false;
    switch(requestCode){
        case 9:
            permissionGranted = grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            break;
    }
    if(permissionGranted){
        phoneCall();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "You don't assign permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void phoneCall(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:12345678900"));
        mActivity.startActivity(callIntent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "You don't assign permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**For call from dialer (No permission needed):**

```
   fun callFromDailer(mContext: Context, number: String) {
        try {
            val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
            callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$number")
            mContext.startActivity(callIntent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No SIM Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

**For direct call from app(Permission needed):**

```
  fun callDirect(mContext: Context, number: String) {
        try {
            val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
            callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$number")
            mContext.startActivity(callIntent)
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Need call permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No SIM Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this as well:

```
String uri = "tel:" + posted_by.replaceAll("[^0-9|\\+]", "");
```

Answer (score 5):

For making a call activity using intents, you should request the proper permissions.

For that you include uses permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Then include the following code in your activity

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Creating intents for making a call
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    mActivity.startActivity(callIntent);

}else{
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "You don't assign permission.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this - one can use the GUI for entering permissions. Eclipse take care of where to insert the permission tag and more often then not is correct

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        mContext,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != 
              PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, new 
                  String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 0);
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Number")));
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android for certain functionalities you need to add the permission to the Manifest file.

1. Go to the Projects AndroidManifest.xml
2. Click on the Permissions Tab
3. Click on Add
4. Select  Uses Permission
5. See the snapshot below[image]

6.Save the manifest file and then run your project.
Your project now should run as expected.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
11-25 14:47:01.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302): blah blah...requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

^ The answer lies in the exception output "**`requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE`**" :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    final public void Call(View view){

    try {

        EditText editt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        String str=editt.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:"+str));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"App failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**use this code in Kotlin**

```
fun makeCall(context: Context, mob: String) {
        try {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)

            intent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$mob")
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                "Unable to call at this time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

String phone = "9553290143";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));

startActivity(intent);