# android: How to call the number by android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make phone call using intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

Please give me code for calling the number through android Application.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

**Edit**: Must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` in Manifest as      well.

Comment: Must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` in Manifest as well.

Comment: Use **Intent.ACTION_DIAL** instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL` and you can get rid of permissions in `Manifest`

Comment: Even I add permission and exported as true but not worked, when I change from `Intent.ACTION_CALL` to `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` worked.

Answer (score 71):

Try this,

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

And remember add this `CALL_PHONE` permission to your `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

This may helps you.