# How to use phone number in alert dialog android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to use default phone number and pass that in alert dialog.How it's possible. I have tried,but it force close.Please solve my issue. Thanks in advance. My coding is as follows:

```
case R.id.menu_settings:
String phoneNo ="123456789";
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("Do you want to call us?"+phoneNo);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
String uri = "123456789";
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
 }
});
alert.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
    }

  });
  alert.show();
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat stacktrace too.

Comment: Duplicate. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551912/android-how-to-call-the-number-by-android-application) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Uri should be in the format `tel:########`

```
String uri = "tel:123456789";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because at least 1 of 2 reasons.

1. You do not have the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` in your manifest
2. Your `Uri` is in an incorrect format. Change it from

   `String uri = "123456789"` to 
   `String uri = "tel:123456789"`