# Android - Launch Google Voice app and dial number

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android, google-voice

We are working on an Android tablet-only app. We need to be able to launch the Google Voice app for a certain telephone number programmatically.

We tried this (which it would probably work to launch the phone if our app wasn't running on a tablet), but it did not work:

```
var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView);
string uri = "tel:" + number;
intent.SetData (Uri.Parse (uri));
activity.StartActivity (intent);
```

Code ported from Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android).

All it does is popup a box to add the number to a contact--which is not what we want.

Any ideas? We can't find any examples online of doing this, and I'm sure it would use a completely different url scheme, etc.

- NOTE: our app is Mono for Android, but Java answers will work for us just as well

Comment: From my examination of Google Voice, I doubt that this is possible. It certainly is not supported -- they offer no activities with any likely `<intent-filter>` that fits your needs.

Comment: I think you might be right, I'll wait a few days and see if anyone else has some input.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you post a little more info on how you looked at the `intent-filter` of an existing app?  I can mark you as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my examination of Google Voice, I doubt that this is possible. It certainly is not supported -- they offer no activities with any likely  that fits your needs.

> can you post a little more info on how you looked at the intent-filter of an existing app?

There is a handy app on the Play Store called [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore), from Sony. It lets you inspect various details about installed apps, including having it effectively regenerate the manifest from data held in `PackageManager`.

So, I installed Google Voice and examined it in AppXplore, sifting through all the activities (there's a zillion of 'em) for interesting `<intent-filter>` elements. I was a bit surprised that they didn't offer a `tel:` filter, and I didn't see anything else likely to be relevant.