# Add a call button to an Android App

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a call button. Which would be button14. All the other buttons open a WebActivity file that has the strings as links in it.

I'm real new to programming in Android. I had someone help me create the app in the first place but he is out of town and I need to get this done. Any help would be great!!

```
package com.myapp.programname;

import com.myapp.programname.R;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onButton(View view) {

        int index = -1;
        int id = view.getId();

        if (id == R.id.button1) {

            index = 0;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button2) {

            index = 1;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button3) {

            index = 2;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button4) {

            index = 3;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button5) {

            index = 4;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button6) {

            index = 5;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button7) {

            index = 6;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button8) {

            index = 7;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button9) {

            index = 8;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button10) {

            index = 9;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button11) {

            index = 10;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button12) {

            index = 11;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button13) {

            index = 12;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.button14) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }

        else {

            index = 0;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("link", index);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is the WebActivity Code Also

```
package com.myapp.programname;

import com.myapp.programname.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return false;
        }
    }

    String links[] = {"http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com,
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com",
            "http://somesite.com"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("link", 0);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(links[index]);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.web, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the default built-in Android "call application" or whatever the user wants to use. To do this use an implicit intent and eventually put in the bundle additional information, like the number to call.

Answer (score 2):

You can prepare a `Intent` for a phone call and launch it like this...

```
String phoneNumber = "555-555-5555";
Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

And don't forget to include this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Reference from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android).

Comment: Adding the Above code does open the dialer and calls the number but I get a application force close error.