# Call Number from Android App from Native calling app programatically

Tags: android

I use  followoing permission to make phone call from my application

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Here is my code for making call.

```
 Intent iniCall=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 iniCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9849199291");
 startActivity(iniCall);
```

But It start the Skype Application instead of starting Default Calling Application.

How to call from default calling application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make phone call using intent in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

Comment: it starts the skype app because it is the app the user has chosen to be the **default app** to handle the calling action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `Pre-Lollipop` devices you need to use `com.android.phone` as package name and in `Lollipop` you need to use `com.android.server.telecom` as package name.

Try this code:

```
Intent iniCall=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   iniCall.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom"); 
}else{
   iniCall.setPackage("com.android.phone"); 
} 
iniCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+9849199291);
startActivity(iniCall);
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

mainactivity code:

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String phnum = edittext.getText().toString();
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
    startActivity(callIntent);
   }
  });
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the method that doesn't require a permission, but does require the user to press dial in the dialpad like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```