# How can I call a phone number through my android app?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I made a simple app that contains emergency numbers in a list view, and what I want to do is that when I click on the contact on the list view I'm able to call a phone number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make phone call using intent in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write under button onclick

```
    String number = "123456789";//mobile number
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example about how you can call to number 123456789.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Just put it in OnItemClickListener() method of your listView.
Hope that will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String mono = "9876543210";//mobile number
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +mono));
    startActivity(intent);
```

in Manifest set permission CALL_PHONE