# Making call is not working on Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I've tried almost every kind of help on google, but it's still not working on my project.

I'm trying to make a website to an Android Web App, and there's `<a href="tel:>` tag on the website when the browser's window has become small size.

When I make it as an Android Web Application, the phonecall is not working even though I did the right way that other people guided me to do. The Application keep shows me "This page is not available"

Asking for your help!

Below is my code

[MainActivity.java]

```
package com.example.user.webviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    private String mCurrentUrl;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        String url = "http://dongari.or.kr/handongdae/";

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        });

        mCurrentUrl = null;
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.user.webviewtest/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.user.webviewtest/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

            if (mCurrentUrl != null && url != null && url.equals(mCurrentUrl)) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                mCurrentUrl = url;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

[AndroidManifest.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.webviewtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DIAL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You may have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you should return false

this  will work fine for you:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had setup in this way :

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){


 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx)
            {
               // viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
               // return false;



                if (urlx.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(urlx));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if(Uri.parse(urlx).getHost().endsWith("google.com")) {

                    return true;
                }

               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlx));
                viewx.getContext().startActivity(intent);


                return false;


            }

        });
```

the tel call had to be called before google.com call.