# Is it possible to modify the phone number when calling

Tags: android

To use a prepaid card with the currents contact phone numbers of the phone, the phone number must be precede with some numbers. 
I'd like to know if there is a way to create an app which will modify the phone number when calling. Or have a pop up shown when calling in order to choose whether or not calling throw the prepaid card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to create this app.

You can show the dialer and all as part of your app's GUI and receive the number as input form the user. When the user presses the Call button (again, you have to implemente all the GUI yourself) just append the additional country code and what not (and if you need, show a dialog). You can perform a call using Implicit Intent.

Basically, what you can do with an implicit intent is invoke an application picker (like the one you see for opening links) for phone.

Link : [how to make phone call using intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

The permission `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`

> allows an application to see the number being dialed during an
>   outgoing call with the option to redirect the call to a different
>   number or abort the call altogether.

might be what you are looking for to build your app using some receiver for `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`