# How to Call the Secrect Codes of Android Phone?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application which calls the secret code in Android phone. Say `*#*#4636#*#*` code brings the Display information about Phone, Battery and Usage statistics.

I had created a button and while pressing the button, I want the above Code to be executed.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "*#*#4636#*#*"));
startActivity(intent);
```

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`