# can i make list view put numbers to call it from button in activity

Tags: android

how to make the list view parse number of phones which i want to call with this in button in another a

```
public class OtorhinolaryngologyClass1 extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otorhinolaryngology_class1);
    Button call= (Button) findViewById(R.id.call1);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(int position) {

}
public void setTitles(final String title){
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textt1)).setText(title);
}

public void call1(View view) {

}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODpRH.png)

Comment: I'm sorry for frequent mistakes too hard to post here

Comment: There is a large yellow box that teaches you how to format your question correctly

Comment: Besides that, please do not post code in images

Comment: can you help me in this

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. You called `setTitles` in the Activity class, which only sets a TextView.  A list doesn't parse phone numbers. You'd need something special to do that, not a list itself

Comment: can i send numbers of phones to button in the activity the button make call

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-phone-call-using-intent-in-android

Comment: In each case text in list view wanted to send number to be contacted in saves in button in activity  to be contacted through

Comment: Then use `call.setText`... Again, sorry, it's unclear. (Your listview click listener is really not correct with the unnecessary switch statement)

Comment: any more help??

Comment: I've already told you... If you want to update the button, then do it. What's stopping you? You're only updating a TextView right now

Comment: thank you very much