# Launching a dialler from app in android gives error

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to dial a user from my app launching the dialer in android

**I have provided the manifest permission**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

**I have also provided the runtime permission**

**Code:**

```
private fun startPhoneDial(phoneNo: String) {
        val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        //callIntent.data = Uri.parse(phoneNo)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone")
        }else{
            callIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom")
        }
        callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNo")
        startActivity(callIntent)
    }
```

**Error-Stack-Trace**:

```
Exception: Method threw 'android.content.ActivityNotFoundException' exception.

Message: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx pkg=com.android.phone }
```

Comment: Error suggests that is is no app on phone with package `com.android.phone` that can handle intent . Try to remove package and also create a intent chooser

Comment: Are you running it on a tablet or something with no telephony app?

Comment: Even I comment out `callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone")` still i get the error

Comment: @SaurabhThorat ... I am running on my phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this.

```
val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

```
fun callANumber(context: Context, phoneNo: String) {
     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo)) {
        return
    }

    val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNo")
    
    try {
        context.startActivity(callIntent)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"No Activity found which can handle intent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: CALL_PHONE is not needed to open the dialer. It's only needed when you want to call directly without user's interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to remove that hardcoded package instead just use the generic intent for opening the dialer as this will call the available intent instead of given one.

Or you just place this below code after handling the activity not found exception.

```
private fun startPhoneDial(phoneNo: String) {
        val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        //callIntent.data = Uri.parse(phoneNo)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone")
        }else{
            callIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom")
        }
        callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNo")
        try{
        startActivity(callIntent)        
        }
        catch(exp : ActivityNotFoundException){
         val intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:${phoneNo}"));
         startActivity(intent); 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can call directly ACTION_DIAL.

```
            val phone = "+919898989898"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null))
            startActivity(intent)
```

reference:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18973484/2553615

Answer (score 0):

Because it's the opposite way... In versions smaller than lollipop, it's:

```
com.android.phone
```

From versions starting at lollipop, it's:

```
com.android.server.telecom
```

So you should just swap your greater-than sign like:

```
private fun startPhoneDial(phoneNo: String) {
    val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    //callIntent.data = Uri.parse(phoneNo)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone")
    }else{
        callIntent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom")
    }
    callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNo")
    startActivity(callIntent)
}
```