# I still don't get why I'm getting an error: with intent

Tags: android, kotlin

Why i get an error on intent?
I want to call a number when a clicking on a floating button.

ContextCompat.startActivity(intent), here a get the error (intent)

Type mismatch.
Required:Context
Found:Intent

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Secretariaat wordt gebeld", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
        makePhoneCall("0123456")
    }

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
   }





fun makePhoneCall(number: String) : Boolean {
    try {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:$number"))
        ContextCompat.startActivity(intent)
        return true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `ContextCompat.startActivity(intent)`? Just use `this.startActivity(intent)`. I don't even think `this` is necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't get the error anymore, but it isn't still calling the phone number!!

Comment: That wasn't your question. Accept one of the answers and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`ContextCompat.startActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat.html#startactivity) takes three arguments, `Context`, `Intent` and a `Bundle` as extra options (can be null)

```
ContextCompat.startActivity(this, intent, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to invoke method `startActivity()`, you can do it without `ContextCompat` class. If you call this method inside `Activity` class. In that case your code will be like:

```
fun makePhoneCall(number: String) : Boolean {
    try {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:$number"))
        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: But it isn't calling the number, the only thing that happend is showing the message.

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to use static `ContextCompat.startActivity(intent)` use only `startActivity(intent)` as you are already in an Activity
2. To use `Intent.ACTION_CALL` you need call permission in manifest.

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`

There is another solution which I prefer. Use `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL` which doesn't require permission.

Your code would be:

```
fun makePhoneCall(number: String) : Boolean {
    try {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:$number"))
        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    }
}
```

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45790561/1263362)

Comment: ok it works but now I get my keyboard and I want him to call immediately and not to have to confirm again by clicking on the phone-icon.

Comment: I think that's another problem. You can google it according to your need or ask another question. You can accept my answer if it's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: as far I know there is no such option. As this might be a security breach & user need to pay for it. If you really need it than you might need to implement the whole thing in your app.