# No Activity Found To Handle Intent - phone dialer

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a dialer intent and getting this error:
Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx }'
This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionDial);
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + "1700700848");
intent.SetData(uri);
StartActivity(intent)
```

I have tried to find a solution to this problem but nothing worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a phone call using intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-a-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i think this will help you

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + "1700700848");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-a-phone-call-using-intent-in-android)

Comment: Tried it, shows the same error. Thanks for helping me, even though it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways to do this in Xamarin Android as of now:

- Using intent:

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionDial);
  Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + "1700700848");
  intent.SetData(uri);
  activityContext.StartActivity(intent);
  ```
- Xamarin Essentials:

  In your Manifest add:

> If your project's Target Android version is set to Android 11 (R API 30) you must update your Android Manifest

```
  <queries>
  <intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
  <data android:scheme="tel"/>
  </intent>
  </queries>
```

And create a method like below:

```
 public void PlacePhoneCall(string number)
{
    try
    {
        PhoneDialer.Open(number);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException anEx)
    {
        // Number was null or white space
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
    {
        // Phone Dialer is not supported on this device.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Other error has occurred.
    }
}
```

Then use it something like this: `PlacePhoneCall(399287934);`

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin, you can use **Xamarin.Essentials: Phone Dialer**. Just add a simple configuration under the AndroidManifest.xml asking price and you can use it.

More information about it can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/phone-dialer?tabs=android.

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?