# how to initiate call in android ? currently im able to select a contact from contacts but the call is not going

Tags: java, android-studio

this is a part of the app im creating which detects the drowsiness state of a person i.e., if a person's eyes are closed for more than 4 seconds then an alarm sound plays on the phone and a call will be initiated to the picked contact . But the call is not going. tested using logcat to see if the contact name and number is fetched correctly and the output is correct .

````
    // Method to open the contacts list
    public void pickContact() {
        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
    }

    // Constants for handling contact selection result
    private static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;

    // Method to process the selected contact information
    public void processContactSelection(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();

            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    // Get the phone number from the ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone table
                    Cursor phoneCursor = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id},
                            null
                    );

                    if (phoneCursor != null && phoneCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        int numberColumnIndex = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                        mContactName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                        mContactNumber = phoneCursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);

                        Log.d("EmergencyContactManager", "Contact Name: " + mContactName);
                        Log.d("EmergencyContactManager", "Contact Number: " + mContactNumber);
                    }

                    if (phoneCursor != null) {
                        phoneCursor.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }



    // Method to call the emergency contact
    public void callEmergencyContact() {
        String number = "tel:" + mContactNumber;
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
        mActivity.startActivity(callIntent);
    }



    // You can add getters and setters for the contact details if needed.
}```
````

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275678/how-to-make-a-phone-call-using-intent-in-android